# git commit prints out message in a single line

Tags: git, commit

I am trying to commit a file using Git. I am using notepad to enter the commit message for the changes however the lines below which should be printed in multiple lines (line endings with CRLF) ,they are joined together. I have checked the `git config --global core.autocrlf` and it was true in the config file. Any ideas on what is happening?

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. 
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch mo-dev 
# Changes to be committed: modified:  
# README.txt new file:   
# new_mo_file.txt
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? I'd recommend using notepad++, which can correctly display files with LF line endings

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64. How do you change it? using Git commands? I have configured Git client during installation.

Comment: using notepad to commit the files? can you upload a video?

Comment: Changing what git uses as a text editor: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-set-Notepad-as-the-default-Git-editor-for-commits-instead-of-Vim

Comment: `core.autocrlf` applies to files as they move in and out of commits; it does not apply to temporary files created by `git commit` for the purpose of running your commit message editor. As an aside, it's generally considered unwise to depend on `core.autocrlf` for those files either: use `.gitattributes` directives instead. In any case this has no bearing on your commit message issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a different editor or a graffical git client like gitk.
https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

It is also possible to add your commit message ditectly om the command line with:
git commit -m "enter commit message"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have re-installed Git and it worked fine!